# Restricting the codomain of a smooth map of manifolds to a submanifold is not necessarily smooth.

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

In John Lee's introduction to smooth manifold book he gives the following example:

Example 5.28:

Let $S \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be the figure eight submanifold with the topology and smooth structure induced by the immersion $\beta:(-\pi,pi)$; $\beta(t)=(\sin2t,\sin t)$.

Define a smooth map $G: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ by $G(t)=(\sin2t,\sin t)$. The image of $G$ clearly lies in $S$, but as a map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $S$ it is not even continuous because $\beta^{-1} \circ G$ is not continuous at $t=\pi$.

> I am confused why he is looking at the composition $\beta^{-1}\circ G$ to show that $G$ is not continuous. I think that since $\beta$ is a diffeomorphism, then if $G$ were continuous then this composition would have to be continuous. But I still don't comprehend why we need to look a the composition to show it's discontinuous.
>
> Update:
>   Okay so I think I've figured it out. This has to do with the topology given to the image of injective smooth immersion. It goes as follows: Let $F: N \rightarrow M$ be an injective smooth immersion. Then as in the proof of Lee's proposition 5.18, $S=F(N)$ is topologized by delcaring $U \subset S$ open iff $F^{-1}(U) \subset N$ is open.
>
> In the case at hand our $F$ is the map $\beta$. It's easy to see from how the image of $\beta$ traces out the figure-eight that at $t=\pi$ that the image of the composition $\beta^{-1}\circ G$ jumps from points near $\pi$ back down to zero which is obviously a discontinuity.

Comment: The title is misleading. $S$ is not what we would call a submanifold. It's called an *immersed submanifold*. The point is precisely that the topology messes up.

Comment: @TedShifrin Sorry I should have been more clear. I guess it's different among different authors. When John Lee says "submanifold" he always means an "immersed submanifold". What you're referring to as "submanifold" is what he calls an "embedded submanfiold". 

It is true that if the map is continuous after restricting the codomain to S then it will be smooth. Since an embedded submanifold has the subspace topology this will be the case.

Comment: I haven't carefully looked at all the texts, but I think Lee's language usage here is somewhat unusual. So be careful!